# g++-4.9 on Raspberry Pi 2: undefined reference to `boost::atomics::detail::lockpool::get_lock_for when linking

Tags: c++, linux, boost, patch

I used

> sudo apt-get install libboost1.55-all

to install the boost library on a Raspberry Pi 2. When I try to link the object files of my application, I get the following error:

> In function `scoped_lock':
>   /usr/include/boost/atomic/detail/lockpool.hpp:36: undefined reference to  boost::atomics::detail::lockpool::get_lock_for(void const volatile*)'

I read that this is a bug and that there are patches available:
https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9041

However, I don't really know how to apply the patch (a step by step explanation would be helpful, i tried "patch p0 < ...") and whether there is a more "elegant" solution.

Comment: When i use -lboost_atomic it works. However, I would still be glad for an explanation on how to apply the patch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A patch is applied to the source code before it's build. In your case you are downloading pre-built binaries so the step to apply a patch has passed.

For detailed information on how to apply a patch I found an article [apply patch file using patch command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appy-patch-file-using-patch-command/)